# How to Localize sound files

Tags: ios, localization, audio

I have sounds in my app, which are appropriate for different languages.

How can i load the correct file depending on locale without checking it manually ?

Comment: Please explain more about checking manually and load the correct file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the files to Xcode and then localize them in the right hand side panel:

[image: Screen shot]

You then have a list of localizations:

[image: Screemn shot result]

Then the bundle will pull out the correct file.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

Comment: if i delete the "base" version, (for a sound that i don't have an english version for) what will happen ?

Comment: It will either return `nil` or it might be clever and look for the next preferred localization! I'd hope it would do the latter (which does make more sense) - only suggest I have is to try it I'm afraid :)

Comment: I would prefer the nil version. thanks for your help

Comment: @LenaBru After thinking about it again it might acutally do this (I believe strings might not though) so you then have the knowledge that no files exists for this locale.

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly localized the files in your project, then you'll 'automatically' get the correctly localized path by calling `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resourcePath ofType:type];`